# Blaschke condition on upper half plane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

if f is in $H^{1}$ the Hardy space with integrable norm, and if f is not identically zero, then the zeroes of f (certainly countable in number) satisfy the Blaschke condition.Can any "Blaschke condition" be defined if hardy space is considered on the upper-half plane instead of unit disk. Curious to know if this carries over by the conformal equivalence that maps upper-half plane to unit disk and vice-versa.

Comment: The short answer is "yes." The longer answer is either 1) do the calculation yourself, or 2) look in Garnett's {\it Bounded Analytic Functions} book.

Comment: Garnett's book is a great text and a good suggestion, but I can't resist putting a word in for thevrecent introductory text of Mashreghi http://books.google.ca/books/about/Representation_Theorems_in_Hardy_Spaces.html?id=PvM4VJlKcnkC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blaschke condition in the upper half-plane is $$\sum\left|\Im\frac{1}{z_k}\right|<\infty.$$
For the proof follow the advice given above, that is prove it yourself, or look in a book.
In addition to the books mentioned above, I recommend Koosis Hardy spaces, or Levin,
Distribution of values of entire functions, or de Branges, Hilbert spaces of entire functions.

Comment: @ Alexandre Eremenko.  Are you sure this is right?  I get the condition that the sum  $$\sum 1 - \left | \frac {z_k-i}{z_k+i}\right |$$ be finite and this only agrees with your one under a priori assumptions on the $z_k$

Comment: Yes, I am sure. See Levin, Chap V, section 3. I slightly edited
the formula. 

Comment: @  Alexandre Eremenko ): I could not found the deduction for the upper half plane in the suggested site. Can you please show the deduction or suggest any other link for this ?

Comment: @Empty see [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1308822/223002).